# Is it possible to change the preview surface while recording with Media recorder

Tags: preview, surface, android-mediarecorder

Can anyone help me with solution or lead?I am Recording video using MediaRecorder.I have surfaceview attached to the recorder for preview.I have different Layouts for Portrait and Landscape.Now the preoblem is that When I change the Orientation surface is getting created again(Ofcourse it is so as it is different for landscape n protrait) ..in this case inorder to get the preview I have to stop , then prepare the recorder with new surface and start recorder again.Is it possible to change the preview surface while recording?

surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) I am doing teh following

```
If(recording)
   recorder.Stop();
recorder.reset();
recoder.intialiseFileFormats() ;  //Init AV formats and codecs
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Any help is really appreciable.Thanks

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution for this case?